# Interpretation of combined (!) particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I'm a beginner in QFT and was reading David Tong's lecture notes. While quantizing the field for a complex a scalar field with the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L}=\partial_\mu\psi\partial^\mu\psi^*-M^2\psi^2$$

it is possible to write (consistently) the field operators as

$$\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})=\int \frac{d^3\vec{k}}{(2\pi)^3}\Big(b_{\vec{k}}e^{i\vec{k}.\vec{r}}+c^\dagger_{\vec{k}}e^{-i\vec{k}.\vec{r}}\Big)$$

This gives rise to the particle (created with $b^\dagger$) and it's anti-particle (created with $c^\dagger$).

Now what if we divide the fields to two real and imaginary segments? (Instead of the field and it's complex conjugate)

Then the creation operators will be

$$a_R=\frac{b+c}{2}$$

and

$$a_I=\frac{b-c}{2i}$$

what are these particles (with the exact same mass) ?

---

P.S. It is noteworthy that the number operators for the two basis do not commute. In other words a state with one $real$ particle has no corresponding number of B or C particles!

Comment: The fact that you can decompose the operator into those creation and annihilation operators is inherent to the differential equations it should satisfy. If you decompose it into the real and imaginary components the differential equations are different and therefore the decomposition into "real" and "imaginary" particles does not hold.

Comment: Actually, thinking for a little bit longer, it seems like the differential equations actually are the same. I'll think about it for a bit and come back with a proper answer. Unless someone else has a good explanation already, that is.